# Twitter Bootstrap Nav Dropdown Position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, accordion, pug

In the following JADE my dropdown menu when clicked opens in the very bottom right of the page instead of right below the icon, i have no idea why it is doing this and im in the middle of upgrading to Bootstrap 3.0rc1

This is pull-right in each accordion item.

```
div.alert-success.accordion-toggle.group-accordion-toggle
                            a(data-toggle="collapse", data-parent="#item1", href="#item1", style="text-decoration: none")
                                i.icon-collapse
                                b Item 1

                            div.pull-right
                                a(href="#", data-toggle="dropdown") 
                                    i.icon-pencil
                                ul.dropdown-menu(role="menu", aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu")
                                    li
                                        a(href="google.com") Google
                                    li
                                        a(href="google.com") Google
```

[image: Screenshot of issue when clicking on the icon for menu.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add `btn-group` class to the `div.pull-right` line.